# Can Apple World Travel Adapter Kit be used in Iran

Tags: electronic-items, power, iran

Can you use the [Apple World Travel Adapter Kit](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD837AM/A/apple-world-travel-adapter-kit) in Iran? I want to be able to charge my Macbook. I read somewhere that Iran's voltage is 240 but I purchased the Macbook in the US, any idea if this would work?

Comment: Note that the plug type doesn't affect the voltage

Comment: I suggest you get a generic power adapter and plug your Apple plug into that. A generic adaptor can be used for other things, but the Apple adapter has only one use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Iran](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Iran) does in fact use 240V and European-type plugs. That kit provides only a wall adapter and your MacBook [charger](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs-retina/) takes care of the voltage conversion, so **the answer is yes**.

iPhone chargers are also [universal](http://www.apple.com/shop/question/answers/product/MD810LL/A/would-apple-5w-usb-that-comes-with-iphone-6s-power-adapter-work-on-220v-or-is-it-only-designed-for-110v/Q2JYF7TACFYTFUAFP), just use the right wall adapter.

Comment: thanks :P, also what do you need to charge the iphone using this kit?

Comment: @Tom the phone chargers are universal too, just use the right adapter. Or plug it in the computer :)

Comment: Just make sure it's a charger made by Apple, or some other reputable company. And "original Apple chargers" bought on eBay are often not made by Apple.

Comment: Note that the real voltage is 220V!

Answer (score 3):

The short answer: yes. The longer answer: yes, obviously. :) In particular note the page you linked saying:

> The AC plugs included in the World Travel Adapter Kit directly support outlets in North America, Japan, China, United Kingdom

Woohoo 240V!